# Recalculate height after window resize

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, height, responsive-design

I have a function created that displays a 'speech-bubble' when I hover over the parent object. However the bubble is set to display above the parent object, as calculated by it's height.

I'm trying to work this into a responsive design, and as such the width and height are both dynamic. I've tried to run the function after the window resize with the following code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.popup').popup();
}).trigger('resize');
```

This almost seems to do the trick, but it's quite buggy. You can see what I mean by checking out [this jsfiddle I put together](http://jsfiddle.net/norsewulf/jMG4K/).

The speech bubble works fine before the window is resized, but once it's been resized and you hover over one of the trigger objects the speech bubble animates for what looks like 5 or so repetitions.

No doubt this wasn't originally written for a responsive design and I'm not much of a JS developer, so if anyone sees any clear improvements that could be made I'd be happy to accept them! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the popup() gets bound to the event more than once. Just use this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.popup').popup();
});
```

And, set the position of popup on mouseover.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Once the height of the parent container changes, the speech bubble is no longer in the correct place. Hence why I was running the function inside of the window resize event.  
  
This was kind of difficult to notice in my original jsfiddle because I only had "Lorem Ipsum" in the parent container and the height won't change until the second character dropped to the next line.

Comment: then you have to set the top and left position of popup window on mouseover. this would resolve your issue. However, if you call this function inside window.resize, this would get bound again and again.

Comment: Oh! So I just need to set my height variable inside the mouseover() function? Gah! That's so easy! And it works!!

Ugh that pisses me off. But I'm also happy. Haha thanks for the help!

Comment: yes... just update your mouseover function to set the position of popup div. don't set the position at the time of initialization.

Answer (score 0):

remove -

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.popup').popup();
  }).trigger('resize');
```

and then add

```
  $('.popup').popup();
```

see this - http://jsfiddle.net/im4aLL/jMG4K/2/

Comment: This doesn't work for the same reasons I mentioned to @Pitchai -

When the height of the container changes the speech bubble is no longer in the right place.

Comment: did you see this - http://jsfiddle.net/im4aLL/jMG4K/2/ Its working there. Tell me which browser you are using

Comment: If you read through the comment thread between me and @Pitchai, you'll see why this doesn't work. In your jsfiddle, try shrinking the window until the text goes onto two lines. The speech bubble no longer displays in the correct location.